# How to install Thunderbird in old version Ubuntu 9.xx?

Tags: thunderbird

I tried to used these commands at the root terminal:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The result is it could not find.

Then using the add/ remove GUI, I also could not load the Thunderbird to install.

I have very little Linux command text knowledge. How can I get and install Thunderbird into my old Ubuntu V9.xx?

Comment: please use paste.ubuntu.com and post a link to the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` as well as `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` - thanks.  Which version of v9 - 9.04 or 9.10?  Are you connected to the internet or not?  Just for interest - why have you not upgraded to a supported version of ubuntu such as 10.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.x is unsupported. Please do not use it unless you really know what you're doing. There _will be_ unresolved security issues which can enable remote attackers to abuse your computer. Please upgrade to at least 10.04LTS.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad While it's true that users should upgrade from Ubuntu 9.x, and **you're right that using those releases is dangerous**, *we do currently support that here* and this question should not be closed as off-topic for being about an EoL Ubuntu release. (See the community consensus as expressed by overwhelming votes in favor of allowing EoL questions [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2122/should-questions-about-using-end-of-life-ubuntu-releases-be-closed) and [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3229/dealing-with-past-eol-release-questions).)

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the official thunderbird version provided by Mozilla, instead of the version in official Ubuntu repository provided by Canonical. At least on Ubuntu 9.04 and 9.10, the version in Ubuntu is not very good, and the upstream version is much better.